# md5 possibility value unreasonable?

Tags: variables, encryption, hash, md5

I want to ask about data encryption MD5 could really be 32 characters ..
I take the example of binary to decimal conversion
the way, the number of possible 3-digit binary was equal to 2<sup>3</sup>. The second was in the can because there are only binary 0 and 1.
3 examples of possible binary digit:

```
000 001 010 011
100 101 110 111 -> 8 possible
```

and the possible outcome of binary TSB 3 is 0 s / d 7 -> 8 possible
from there can I conclude, how to find a lot of possibilities for the value of the hash is to calculate your own chances of hash TSB like the example above.
My last question on MD5, we know that 32-digit MD5, well then we can count the number of possibilities,
32 digits it in every one digit has the possibility of small letters az and 0-9, it means there are 26 + 10 = 36 chances per one digit
then if the 32 digits then,
36<sup>32</sup>
= 63340286662973277706162286946811886609896461828096
 means we know that the 32-digit md5 it has the possibility that much, let us round it off just so easy
6300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Surprisingly, I really encrypt md5 in website
http://md5encryption.com/
and
http://www.md5online.org/md5-encrypt.html

with numbers
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
and after I encrypt md5 be like this
bf743ebd7f422b7fd5e4c5f0a90a3303

I thought why not make sense yes ..
Let us count the number of possibilities from the above figures
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
aka "9 No 52"
means the number of chances
10<sup>52</sup> <<
whereas we know that it is only the number of possible md5
6300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (circle result) his alias 63 and 0. No 50,
The value of CLEAR "is smaller than the possibility of the number" 9 No 52 "which is 10<sup>52</sup>

I can be like that?
Indeed every possible results of md5 decrypt it there value2 are equally so?

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you're asking, but MD5 is a hashing algorithm, not an encryption algorithm. Both of the sites you linked to simply calculate MD5 hashes; they don't encrypt anything. Also, it's impossible to encrypt an arbitrary plaintext of >128 bits into a 128-bit ciphertext because of the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Answer (score 1):

- [MD5 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)
  MD5 processes a **variable-length** message into a fixed-length output of 128 bits. The input message is broken up into chunks of 512-bit blocks (sixteen 32-bit words); the message is padded so that its length is divisible by 512.
- Big number
  The big number such as 99999...999 [aka 9 No 52] that you mentioned will be stored with only a few bytes of memory space. Specifically, If it is stored as ascii(0x39 is ascii value for '9'), it only needs 52 bytes--{0x39,0x39,...0x39}. If it is stored as binary value, it will need less than 16 bytes -- because 16 bytes(128 bits) can hold a big number value no more than (2 No 128). That is to say, the big number can be stored/expressed with only tens of bytes. It is not a big deal for MD5 , which has been applied to verify those large download files(millions of bytes).
- [MD5 Collision](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/)
  It seems what you were worried about is some behaviour similar to hash collision. But that's another thing. For MD5,
  It is now well-known that the cryptographic hash function MD5 has been broken(Not really,just the Collision). In March 2005, Xiaoyun Wang and Hongbo Yu of Shandong University in China published an article in which they describe an algorithm that can find two different sequences of 128 bytes with the same MD5 hash. One famous such pair is the following:

  ```
  d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab58712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89 
  55ad340609f4b30283e488832571415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbdf280373c5b 
  d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e2b487da03fd02396306d248cda0 
  e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080a80d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f9652b6ff72a70
  ```

  and

  ```
  d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab50712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89 
  55ad340609f4b30283e4888325f1415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbd7280373c5b 
  d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e23487da03fd02396306d248cda0 
  e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080280d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f965ab6ff72a70
  ```

  Each of these blocks has MD5 hash

  ```
  79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4
  ```